# Why sqlalchemy result dict ignores text() columns?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying the new sqlalchemy 1.4 select() syntax, but when executing this simple query, the result dict misses the column 'graph', but the result list includes it.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from source.Models import Quadrant, Graph

engine = sa.create_engine("postgresql://blahblahblah")

dbsession = sa.orm.Session(engine)

stmt = sa.select(
    Quadrant.id,
    sa.text("jsonb_agg(graph.data order by graph.id) as graphs")
).outerjoin(
    Graph, Quadrant.id == Graph.quadrant_id
).group_by(
    Quadrant.id
)

with dbsession.begin():
    res = dbsession.execute(stmt)
    for r in res:
        print(r.keys())   # -> ['id'] **no graphs here!**
        print(list(r))    # -> [0, {aggregated data}]
        print(r[1])       # -> {aggregated data}
```

Is there a way to let the result as dict includes the text column?

I'm not interested in aggregating the result in python: I want to aggregate in postgresql.

Comment: Also you should be able to use [`array_agg`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.array_agg) function instead of using `text()`.

Comment: text() method has no attribute 'label'. 

well, actually the problem was with the function `jsonb_agg`. I used the array_agg to keep the problem simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `literal_column` instead of `text`, if you want to use the text fragment:

```
sa.literal_column("jsonb_agg(graph.data order by graph.id)").label("graph")
```

You can also produce the expression using SQLA constructs:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import aggregate_order_by

sa.func.jsonb_agg(aggregate_order_by(Graph.data, Graph.id)).label('graph')
```